# Select the maximum 9 values and sum the rest in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table with two columns. I need to sort the table by the "**values**" column. Leave **9** maximum values. Sum the remaining values and leave them under the name "*Other*".
Subqueries cannot be used. But I can use window functions.

**initial values:**

```
"name"  "value"
"A"        1
"B"        1
"C"        2
"D"        4
"E"        5
"F"        1
"G"        4
"H"        7
"I"        5
"J"        4
"K"        2
"L"        6
"M"        5
"N"        4
```

**result values:**

```
"name"  "value"
  "H"      7
  "L"      6
  "E"      5
  "I"      5
  "M"      5
  "D"      4
  "G"      4
  "J"      4
  "N"      4
 "Other"   7
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUuDN.png)

Postgresql 14

The code for creating a table, as in the example:

```
create table temp_table
(name varchar(20),
value int);

insert into temp_table values ('A', '1');
insert into temp_table values ('B', '1'); 
insert into temp_table values ('C', '2'); 
insert into temp_table values ('D', '4'); 
insert into temp_table values ('E', '5'); 
insert into temp_table values ('F', '1'); 
insert into temp_table values ('G', '4'); 
insert into temp_table values ('H', '7'); 
insert into temp_table values ('I', '5'); 
insert into temp_table values ('J', '4'); 
insert into temp_table values ('K', '2'); 
insert into temp_table values ('L', '6');
insert into temp_table values ('M', '5'); 
insert into temp_table values ('N', '4');
```

Comment: Do not use images for textual data per [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Copy and paste the text into your question as text.

Comment: OK, I've made corrections. I thought providing the code to create the table was enough. So that nothing has to be copied.

Comment: Read the Images link for why they should not be used. My objections to them 1) Information is not consolidated in one place 2) Link rot, you are depending on an outside site to maintain the information 3) Related to 1) A question should have a beginning, a middle and an end that does not involve jumping around. It should have I'm starting with this data, I want to do this to the data and I want to end up with this output. Having that all  in one place and in order makes the answering process a lot easier.

Comment: Who's making the arbitrary restriction on subqueries? How should you deal with ties?

Comment: `with data as (select *, row_number() over (order by value desc) as rn from T) select case when rn < 10 then name else 'Other' end as name, sum(value) as value from data case when rn < 10 then rn else 10 end`

Comment: @shawnt00 `WITH` is actually a subquery, so it cannot be used(

Comment: What is your definition of a subquery and why such arbitrary restrictions in the first place?

Comment: @shawnt00 this is query for the Apache-Superset. If i use a subquery, i get the message "Custom SQL fields cannot contain sub-queries.". These are the rules of this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two valid solutions that don't involve any kind of "subquery". Hopefully Apache Superset will accept one of these options:

```
select
    case when row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) > 9
         then 'Other' else name end as name,
    case when row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) > 9
         then sum(sum(value)) over (
                      order by sum(value) desc
                      rows between current row and unbounded following)     
         else sum(value) end as value
from T
group by name
order by row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name), value desc
limit 10
```

or

```
select distinct on (
    case when row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) > 9
         then 10 else row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) end
)
    case when row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) > 9
         then 'Other' else name end as name,
    case when row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) > 9
         then sum(sum(value)) over (
                      order by sum(value) desc
                      rows between current row and unbounded following)     
         else sum(value) end as value
from T
group by name
order by case when row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) > 9
              then 10 else row_number() over (order by sum(value) desc, name) end,
         value desc
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Pi1IxGTT

You should be able to parameterize either of these approaches for a different number of results.

Here's a similar method that handles ties that continue past the 9th-place position:

https://dbfiddle.uk/mI8ZuMYP